# Java: error with calling a static method with array parameter written out

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm using BlueJay and I've written this bit of simple code. The method calculates the average of the array's halves and returns the larger integer. It gives back an error with the way I'm calling the method. Can't figure out why. Thank you in advance.

```
public class WritingArrays{
 public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(scoresAverage([2,2,4,4]);
    System.out.println(scoresAverage([4,4,4,2,2,2]);
    System.out.println(scoresAverage([3,4,5,1,2,3]);

public static int scoresAverage(int[] a1){
    return Math.max(average(a1, 0, a1.length/2), average(a1, a1.length/2, a1.length));
}

public static int average(int[] scores, int start, int end){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start-1; i < end; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return sum/(end-start);
}
```

Comment: That's not how you write an array in Java.

Comment: Have a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: could you plz search a query on google for me which is `How to pass array in methods`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not actually creating an array to be passed through the parameter. Also, you seem to be missing a data type. Without this, java does not know whether you are passing in, for instance, an integer array (which you are trying to do), a double array, or a byte array just to name a few. What you should consider is either making an array before passing it in:

```
int[] temp = {2, 2, 4, 4 };
System.out.println(scoresAverage(temp));
```

Or, like I said, creating it and passing it in at the same time.

```
System.out.println(scoresAverage(new int {2, 2, 4, 4}));
```

Make sure to note that in parameters, curley braces are used, just as if you were making a new variable.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe you need to fix your formatting of your sysout statements to look more like this:

```
System.out.println(scoresAverage(new int[]{2, 2, 4, 4}));
```

---

Next, try returning a double value from the average method. So it looks more like this:

```
public static double average(int[] scores, int start, int end){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return sum/(end-start);
}
```

---

If you really need an integer printout you can also cast the value as an int:

```
System.out.println((int)(scoresAverage(new int[]{2, 2, 4, 4})));
```